# How to use generic method that accepts an ArrayList of any type and use the method in the specified type class?

Tags: java

I have a system that has two class: Book and Member. I am trying to do a sort method that can accept an ArrayList of both classes, and sort them before returning to me. Here is how I write my code:

```
public static <T> ArrayList sortElements(Class c, ArrayList<T> elementList) {
        if (c == Book.class) {
            ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object o: elementList) {
                Book book = (Book) o;
                bookList.add(book);
            }
            boolean isBookSorted = false;
            Book bookTemp = null;
            while (!isBookSorted) {
                isBookSorted = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size() - 1; i++) {
                    if ((bookList.get(i).getBookTitle()).compareToIgnoreCase(bookList.get(i+1).getBookTitle())>0) {
                        bookTemp = bookList.get(i);
                        bookList.set(i, bookList.get(i+1));
                        bookList.set(i+1, bookTemp);
                        isBookSorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return bookList;
        }

        if (c == Member.class) {
            ArrayList<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object o: elementList) {
                Member member = (Member) o;
                memberList.add(member);
            }
            boolean isMemberSorted = false;
            Member memberTemp = null;
            while (!isMemberSorted) {
                isMemberSorted = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < memberList.size() - 1; i++) {
                    if ((memberList.get(i).getMemberName()).compareToIgnoreCase(memberList.get(i+1).getMemberName())>0) {
                        memberTemp = memberList.get(i);
                        memberList.set(i, memberList.get(i+1));
                        memberList.set(i+1, memberTemp);
                        isMemberSorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return memberList;
        }
        return elementList;
    }
```

When I am using this method, it shows me a warning: Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.ArrayList'. Is there any better way to implement the sort method in a generic way but still able to use the method inside the class? Because I need to access to Book.getBookTitle(), and Member.getMemberTitle() respectively to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a single function that processes a union of two unrelated classes as parameter is awkward in Java and not how one would usually solve such a problem. In Java you can use method overloading to specify two different functions with the same name but different parameter types.

However for the specific way of sorting, the usual way to specify a sort order in Java is to implement the comparable interface. Then you can use the native Java sort methods, such as `Arrays.sort()` or `java.util.Collections.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea that you create one method for sorting lists of members and books is flawed.

Either the books and members have a clear property that allows them to be compared and thus sorted (using `Collections.sort` or using a `SortedSet`), or you need to have specific methods such as `sortBooksOnTitle(List<Book> books)`. Or you could create your own separate comparator and [use that in `Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Imagine the next programmer, seeing a **generic** sort method, and finding out that it switches between sorting methods depending on the class input. That's definitely failing the principle of least surprise. Or imagine having 10 types of lists to compare, how large will your method become?

Comment: And if you are required to do your own sorting, then simply mimic `Collections.sort` with the comparator...

Answer (score -2):

```
public static <T> List<T> sortElements(Class<T> c, List<T> elementList) {
        if (c == Book.class) {
            boolean isBookSorted = false;
            T bookTemp = null;
            while (!isBookSorted) {
                isBookSorted = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size() - 1; i++) {
                    if((((Book)elementList.get(i))).getBookTitle().compareToIgnoreCase((((Book)elementList.get(i+1))).getBookTitle()) > 0) {
                        bookTemp = elementList.get(i);
                        elementList.set(i, elementList.get(i + 1));
                        elementList.set(i + 1, bookTemp);
                        isBookSorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return elementList;
        }

        if (c == Member.class) {
            boolean isMemberSorted = false;
            T memberTemp = null;
            while (!isMemberSorted) {
                isMemberSorted = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size() - 1; i++) {
                    if ((((Member)elementList.get(i)).getMemberName())
                        .compareToIgnoreCase(((Member)elementList.get(i + 1)).getMemberName()) > 0) {
                        memberTemp = elementList.get(i);
                        elementList.set(i, elementList.get(i + 1));
                        elementList.set(i + 1, memberTemp);
                        isMemberSorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return elementList;
        }

        return elementList;
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers that also fail to solve the cause of the problem will immediately receive a downvote. Sorry.